# Why should classes with __get__ or __set__ know who uses them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encapsulation, descriptor, magic-methods

I just read [about descriptors](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#descriptor) and it felt very unintentional that the behavior of a class can depend on who uses it. The two methods

- `__get__(self, instance, owner)`
- `__set__(self, instance, value)`

do exactly that. They get in the instance of the class that uses them. What is the reason for this design decision? How is it used?

Update: I think of descriptors as normal types. The class that uses them as a member type can be easily manipulated by side effects of the descriptor. Here is an example of what I mean. Why does Python supprt that?

```
class Age(object):
    def __init__(value):
        self.value = value
    def __get__(self, instance, owener):
        instance.name = 'You got manipulated'
        return self.value

class Person(object):
    age = Age(42)
    name = 'Peter'

peter = Person()
print(peter.name, 'is', peter.age)
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood what `__get__` and `__set__`'s arguments do.

Comment: What do you mean by "the instance of the class that uses them"? Example?

Comment: Also, please use the official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol

Comment: @ecatmur Thanks. Could you take a look at the example provided on linked page? It has two descriptors `meter` and `foot` as members where one of them accesses the user using `instance.meter`. That shouldn't be possible from a encapsulation point of view, I think. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__get__` and `__set__` receive no information about who's calling them. The 3 arguments are the descriptor object itself, the object whose attribute is being accessed, and the type of the object.

I think the best way to clear this up is with an example. So, here's one:

```
class Class:
    def descriptor(self):
        return

foo_instance = Foo()
method_object = foo_instance.descriptor
```

Functions are descriptors. When you access an object's method, the method object is created by finding the function that implements the method and calling `__get__`. Here,

```
method_object = foo_instance.descriptor
```

calls `descriptor.__get__(foo_instance, Foo)` to create the `method_object`. The `__get__` method receives no information about who's calling it, only the information needed to perform its task of attribute access.

Comment: When calling a descriptor, Python passes in *just* the instance and class. It just so happens that most `__get__` *implementations* are methods, so the `self` is passed in by the method object. But you can, in principle, use a module with a `__get__` *function* and it still would be used as a descriptor.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Huh? Are you sure that's accurate? Can you provide an example? I'm pretty sure `__get__` follows the normal special method rules, with lookup only on the class and all that, so I don't think a module-level `__get__` function would do anything.

Comment: *`__get__` and `__set__` receive no information about who's calling them.* Alright, but they know who's attribute they are. Since descriptors are just types (are they?), they shouldn't know about the class using them as members. You could write a descriptor with side effects that overwrite other attributes of the class unintentionally.

Comment: @danijar: Should methods not know whose method they are? I think you may be seeing the `instance` and `owner` arguments as more magical than they are. The descriptor does not pull context out of thin air. When you access an attribute, the attribute access mechanism finds the descriptor and *tells* it, "Hey, this object of this type needs its attribute computed."

Comment: @danijar: Why do you find the idea of a descriptor modifying the class more objectionable than a method modifying the class? Are you used to languages like Java, where attribute access is guaranteed to be a very simple, side-effect-free operation? In Python, `foo.bar` can do anything `foo.bar()` could.

Comment: @user2357112 Methods live in the class, so they can access it. But descriptors are external classes, that just get used as a member type. So descriptors can load in modifications into a class by just using a type. In object oriented languages, that wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Methods are external objects too. So?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Are they methods external? It is common to share class scope with methods, but not with types used. Maybe this is why I found it questionable. However, I got a better understanding of the concept now.

Comment: @danijar: Methods aren't special. Other descriptors "live in the class" exactly as much as methods do. In fact, you can define a function outside the class, halfway across your program's architecture, and assign it to `Class.method_name`, and it'll function seamlessly as the `method_name` method of the `Class` class.

Comment: @danijar: remember: in Python **everything** is dynamic, and `self` in methods is not special. It is just a reference to the instance; any *other* reference to the instance has the same access.

Answer (score 1):

Descriptors are used to implement *binding behaviour*; a descriptor requires a context, the object on which they act.

That object is the `instance` object passed in.

Note that without a descriptor, attribute access on an object acts directly on the object attributes (the instance `__dict__` when setting or deleting, otherwise the class and base classes attributes are searched as well).

A descriptor lets you delegate that access to a separate object entirely, encapsulating getting, setting and deleting. But to be able to do so, that object needs access to the context, the instance. Because getting an attribute also normally searches the class and its bases, the `__get__` descriptor method is also passed the class (`owner`) of the instance.

Take functions, for example. A function is a descriptor too, and binding them to an instance produces a method. A class can have any number of instances, but it makes little sense to store bound methods on all those instances when you create the instance, that would be wasteful.

Instead, functions are bound dynamically; you look up the function name on the instance, the function is found on the class instead, and with a call to `__get__` the function is bound to the instance, returning a method object. This method object can then pass in the instance to the function when called, producing the `self` argument.

Comment: Isn't a descriptor a class itself? I think you should inherit from a type to change its binding behavior, instead of letting the using class worry about that.

Comment: @danijar: yes, but it is **not the instance**. It is a reusable object; functions are descriptors too, which is how methods are bound to instances, but the functions can be bound to any instance as required.

Comment: So setting `instance.name` in my example would resolve to `peter.age.name` instead of `peter.name`?

Comment: No, it'd be `peter.name`. **This is by design**.

Answer (score 1):

An example of the descriptor protocol in action is *bound methods*. When you access an instance method `o.foo` you can either call it immediately or save it into a variable: `a = o.foo`. Now, when you call `a(x, y, z)` the instance `o` is passed to `foo` as the first `self` parameter:

```
class C(object):
    def foo(self, x, y, z):
        print(self, x, y, z)
o = C()
a = o.foo
a(1, 2, 3)   # prints <C instance at 0x...> 1 2 3
```

This works because functions implement the descriptor protocol; when you `__get__` a function on an object instance it returns a bound method, with the instance bound to the function.

There would be no way for the above to work without the descriptor protocol giving access to the object instance.

Comment: Man, everyone went for the same example. Maybe I should've used `property`.